# using req.params to work with an array is failing

Tags: express, mongoose

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4];
```

If I post to 'api/myArray' and I want to retrieve these values, the following does not work:

```
'api/:var'
field : {blah: req.params.var[0], blah2: req.params.var[1]}
```

This does not work, and after console I realized it is no longer an array. Instead, var is now 1,2,3,4 instead of [1,2,3,4]. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

**1st:**

while sending you can serialize it

```
JSON.stringify(var)
```

and recieve it as

```
JSON.parse(var)
```

**2nd:**

Post with `formdata` instead

you can use `req.body` instead of `params`

then you can access like

```
req.body.var[0]
```

Comment: I realized how to do it, but I wanted to try it like this too. It doesn't work when I use req.body.var[0]. I probably don't understand the posting with formdata sentence, going to look it up

Comment: @brucelee yea formdata means posting with an object along not in url

Answer (score 0):

My excuses. I should really have tried harder to find out how to do this.

req.params.var.split(',') would do this